# Red Amber Green sequential palette for treemap in R

Tags: r, treemap

is there a color scale palette that can give sequential RAG color for a treemap. 
I tried "RgYlGn" but due to the range being less over 28 unique values, the colors come out as all Green or Yellow. What I want is the least value being red and median being yellow and max being green with a sequential color gradient from red to green

Answer (score 0):

The function colorRampPalette might be useful to you.

```
colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))
```

Comment: thanks Jean,  Im not sure what am I doing wrong here, likely i havent understood some syntax but the below is giving an error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. treemap(tmp,index=c("SDUnit","Designation"),vSize="Freq",vColor="Ave",type="value",palette=colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green")))